# Python pandas - sum column values and create a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am expecting output of the Pandas Dataframe to be summed and return as list sorted in descending.

**Example: df has below values**

```
         a      b        c 
------------------------------
0        3      5        0
1        0      1        2
2        1      2        1
```

df.sum(axis = 1, skipna = True) will sum the columns and return as

```
a = 4
b = 8
c = 3
```

I wanted the result as [b, a, c]. How to get as list?

Comment: do you want it sorted?

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1)` does not produce the output you indicate

Comment: yes, I wanted it sorted descending

Comment: This example is to find the most frequent used words from the dataframe

Comment: I tried top_dict = { } for c in df.columns: cnt = df[c].sum() top_dict[c]=cnt. This creates {'a': 4, 'b':8,'c':3}

Comment: So do you want a list or dict?

Comment: Wanted as list. Counter example works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) to order output Serie,after use [pandas.Series.tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) or [pandas.Series.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) to convert to list or to dict:

```
my_sum_serie=df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False) #get a ordered pandas Series
print(my_sum_serie)
my_list=my_sum_serie.tolist() #get a list
print(my_list)
my_dict=my_sum_serie.to_dict() #get a dict
print(my_dict)


b    8
a    4
c    3
dtype: int64
[8, 4, 3]
{'b': 8, 'a': 4, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum` returns a pandas `Series` which has an index. When sorted the index is rearranged as well

```
df.sum(skipna=True).sort_values(ascending=False).index.to_list()

['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: from collections import Counter

c = Counter(**dict(df.sum(axis=0)))
add_stop_words = [word for word, count in c.most_common() if count > 6]
add_stop_words